# Is it possible to have one solution for many actors and/or services?

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-actor

is it possible to have one solution for many actors and/or services, or does each actor, service, require their own solution with their own host?

How do you register such services living next to each other?

Current I have

```
> ActorRuntime.RegisterActorAsync(...) 
> ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceTypeRegistered(...)
```

and it's blowing up, saying:

> Invalid Service Type

after I've added an Actor to the solution.

I can't find any examples of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't combine Reliable Actors and Reliable Services within one *service*. However, you can combine them within one Visual Studio solution and one Service Fabric application.

Take a look at the [data aggregation sample](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/service-fabric-dotnet-data-aggregation/) for an example of an application/VS solution with a mixture of the two types.

Comment: Thanks, it basically just works after adding actors/services into the solution, I did extra stuff that broke it. What is a bit confusing that each actor/service project has it's own Program host, unlike other typical solutions